# Sum two enormous long in Java

Tags: java, integer, long-integer, biginteger, integer-overflow

I wrote this method which search in the arrayList if there are two numbers which sum equals the variable **elem**. The problem is that the sum of the variable exceed the dimension of the long type. How can I write it?

```
public static boolean searchSum(ArrayList<Long> array, long elem) {
   int left = 0, right = array.size()-1;
   while (left<right) {
     long n1=Long.valueOf(array.get(left));
     long n2=Long.valueOf(array.get(right));
     if ((n1+n2)==elem) return true;
     else if ((n1+n2)<elem) left++;
     else right--;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: `BigInteger` maybe?

Comment: Note that `long n1=Long.valueOf(array.get(left));` is getting the `Long` from `array`, unboxing it, invoking `Long.valueOf` which is boxing it again, and then unboxing it to assign to the variable. `long n1 = array.get(left);` is just unboxing once, and it's more concise too.

Comment: Didn't you forget to mention some preliminaries like `List<Long> array` being ordered non-descendingly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). It can store immutable arbitrary-precision integer.

For example:

```
public BigInteger sum(Long number1, Long number2) {
    BigInteger bigNumber1 = BigInteger.valueOf(number1);
    BigInteger bigNumber2 = BigInteger.valueOf(number2);
    BigInteger result = bigNumber1.add(bigNumber2);
    return result;
}
```

In this case, you can rewrite this method like this:

```
public static boolean searchSum(ArrayList<Long> array, long elem) {

    BigInteger bigElem = BigInteger.valueOf(elem);        
    int left = 0, right = array.size() - 1;

    while (left < right) {
        BigInteger n1 = BigInteger.valueOf(array.get(left));
        BigInteger n2 = BigInteger.valueOf(array.get(right));
        BigInteger sum = n1.add(n2);

        if (sum.equals(bigElem)) {
            return true;
        } else if (sum.compareTo(bigElem) < 0) {
            left++;
        } else {
            right--;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `BigInteger` to tell the sum of two like signed numbers (here: `long`s) overflowed.

- if both summands have different signs: no overflow
- both summands positive: overflow iff sum < any(every) summand
- both summands negative: overflow iff any(every) summand < sum

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend writing it by adding individual digits and if it is equal to or greater than what the long length is you split it into either two longs or an array and access digits that way for longer math.